# I am trying to find a value of multiple factorials . both values will be divided by like 100!/98! =?

Tags: c#

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your number: ");
        int number= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        double factorial = Factorial(number,number2);

        Console.WriteLine("Factorial of " + number +" / "+ number2 + " = " + factorial );

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    //Factorial function added
    public static double Factorial(int number, int number2)
    {
        if (number == 1 && number2 ==1 )
        {
            return 1;
        }
        double factorial = 1;
        double factorial1 = 1;
        double factorial2 = 1;
        for (int i = number, j = number2; i >= 1 && j >= 1; i--, j--)
        {
            factorial1 = (factorial * i);
            factorial2 = (factorial * j);
            factorial = factorial1 / factorial2;

        }
        return factorial;

    }
```

Comment: Hint, you don’t need to evaluate the factorial if either one. Write down in a piece of paper `5!/3!` and reason it out...

Comment: So... what's the issue you're having? What is the actual question? All you have is code. Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: I m facing the problem is after this code execute is not comming the correct answer.. the number2 is not getting the proper value

Comment: I am trying to.divide by two factorial number like 100!/98! =9900. but output is not correct why?

Answer (score 2):

Your attempted solution is simply so overcomplicated, I wouldn't know where to begin. This usually happens when you don't stop to think about how you'd resolve this problem by hand:

So, the question is, whats `5!/3!`? Ok, lets write it out:

```
(5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1) / (3 * 2 * 1)
```

Wow, that looks like it can be simplified simply to `5 * 4`.

The key insight here is that `m! % n! = 0` if `n` is less or equal to `m`.  In other words, `m!` is always divisible by `n!` because there is always an integer `r` such that `r * n! = m!`, and you don't need to evaluate `m!` or `n!` to figure out what `r` is, you simple do:

```
r = m * (m - 1) * (m - 2) * ... * (n + 1); // m >= n
```

If `n > m`, `r` is zero unless you are looking for a real number solution in which case you would simply evaluate `r` as `n! / m!` and then return `1.0 / r` because `m! / n!` = `1 / (n! / m!)`.

How to evaluate `r`?

```
public static long DivideFactorials(int m, int n)
{
     if (n > m)
         return 0;

     var r = 1L;

     for (var k = m; k > n; k--)
         r *= k;

     return r;
}
```

Or the real number solution:

```
public static double DivideFactorials(int m, int n)
{
     if (n > m)
         return 1 / DivideFactorials(n, m);

     var r = 1.0;

     for (var k = m; k > n; k--)
         r *= k;

     return r;
}
```

Comment: 2 different ones are easier to understand - and as is both are easier to groke then mine +1

Comment: Oh great. The last one is working and so easy to understand!!! but if i want to m>n than ?

Comment: @IqramHasanRabbi Both solutions already give you the answer for all cases; `m > n`, `m == n` or `m < n`.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to save your try:

```
public static double Factorial(int number, int number2)
{
    if (number == 1 && number2 == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    double facNum = 1;
    double facNum2 = 1;

    // counting up is easier, we start at 2 as we initialized to 1
    // we count up to the max of both numbers
    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.Max(number, number2); i++) 
    {
        if (i <= number)
            facNum *= i;  // we mult this until we reached number

        if (i <= number2)
            facNum2 *= i; // we mult this until we reach number2
    }

    // return the devision of both - this wont handle number < number2 well!
    return facNum / facNum2; // do this outside the loop
}
```

---

If I had to create a solution:

Factorial division of integers has 3 outcomes (I can think of):

**`N! / O!`   with `N == O`:**

```
 let N=3, O=3
 N! = 1*2*3
 O! = 1*2*3
 N! / O! = 1*2*3/(1*2*3) == 1
```

**`N! / O!`   with `N > O`:**

```
 let N=5, O=3
 N! = 1*2*3*4*5
 O! = 1*2*3
 N! / O! == 1*2*3*4*5/(1*2*3) == 4*5 == 20
```

**`N! / O!`   with `N < O:`**

```
 let N=3, O=5
 N! = 1*2*3
 O! = 1*2*3*4*5
 N! / O! == 1*2*3/(1*2*3*4*5) == 1/(4*5) == 1/20
```

Based on this I would model the problem like that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

internal class Program
{
    public static decimal CalcFactDivision(int n1, int n2)
    {
        // calclulate the division of a factorial by another, num1 must be >= num2
        IEnumerable<int> getRemaining(int num1, int num2)
        {
            // special cases: div by 0 and 0 div something
            if (num2 == 0)
                num2 = 1; // 0! == 1
            else if (num1 == 0)
                return new[] { 0 };

            // get all numbers that make up the factorial in one step 
            // I can guarantee that num1 will always be bigger then num2
            // by how I call this
            return Enumerable.Range(num2 + 1, num1 - num2);
        }

        // calculate the product of an ienumerable of ints
        int product(IEnumerable<int> nums) => nums.Aggregate((a, b) => a * b);

        if (n1 == n2)
            return 1;
        else if (n1 > n2) // use product(...) to calc
            return product(getRemaining(n1, n2));
        else // flip them and use 1/product(...) to calc
            return (decimal)1 / product(getRemaining(n2, n1));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var a in Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
            Console.WriteLine($"{a}! / {10 - a}! = {CalcFactDivision(a, 10 - a)} ");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1! / 9! = 0,0000027557319223985890652557
2! / 8! = 0,0000496031746031746031746032
3! / 7! = 0,0011904761904761904761904762
4! / 6! = 0,0333333333333333333333333333
5! / 5! = 1
6! / 4! = 30
7! / 3! = 840
8! / 2! = 20160
9! / 1! = 362880
10! / 0! = 3628800
```

Comment: In ur CalcFactDivision Giving an error. That's why this code is not running.

Comment: @IqramHasanRabbi my code -as is- runs. How else would it manage to output? You might not have copied 100% of it or modified it somehow if it gives _you_ an error. What does the error say?